# Spring 3.2 Test, com.jajway not included as dependency

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

My tests were failing because of a class not found exception on

`import com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException;`

within

```
org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper;
```

Manually adding the jayway dependency to my maven pom removed this error and my test ran as expected.

Have I found a bug, or do I need to add a different spring jar as well as spring test ?

Comment: Are you using Maven 2 or 3?

Comment: Can you update the answer with jayway maven coordinates and repository details. I am also getting the same exception, but for the coordinates I have given the dependencies are not getting downloaded

Answer (score 14, accepted):

External dependencies (e.g., JUnit, Mockito, Easy Mock, JayWay, etc.) are not included in Spring, so it is necessary to explicitly add them (Ant/Maven/Ivy dependency, or jar files) to the project's classpath.

Comment: The OP states he's using Maven. Usually Maven includes transitive dependencies, such as JUnit. The problem in this case is that it's marked as optional in the POM. You should never need to add them manually to the classpath.

Answer (score 45):

In my case

Having test code what contained **jsonPath** usage:

```
 mockMvc.perform(get("/api/userDetails").header("Authorization", base64ForTestUser).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("userName").value("testUser"));
```

I was getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/InvalidPathException
```

and

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException
```

This error was directly caused by lack of such dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this dependency worked

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you want to use another version of json-path-assert you can review the following repository:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path